# evaluate $lim_{n \to \infty}\left (\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^n$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^n$$

In general we look at $\lim(x+yi)$ as $\lim(x,y)$ which we obviously can not here.

So I looked at $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left(1+\sqrt{3}i\right)^n}{2^n}$$

$1+\sqrt{3}i=2e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$

So $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{2e^{\frac{\pi i n}{3}}}{2^n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{e^{\frac{\pi i n}{3}}}{2^{n-1}}$$

But I still can not get rid of the imaginary part

Comment: `1+3i=...` That's wrong. $|1+3i|=\sqrt{10} \gt 2\,$. Did you mean a $\sqrt{3}$ somewhere, maybe?

Comment: @dxiv sorry you are right edited

Comment: I wrote an answer with $\;3i\;$ instead of $\;\sqrt3\,i\;$ ...It is not that it is wrong: it is just that the limit then doesn't exist finitely.

Comment: @DonAntonio deeply sorry, I will double check next time when copying from my notebook

Comment: $\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n = (\cos(\pi/3) + i~\sin(\pi/3))^n$ then just use de moivre's theorem.  Or just graph $\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt 3}{2}\right)^n$ on a complex plane and watch what it does, should be pretty clear after a few.

Comment: The question is utterly trivial. $\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is a primitive sixth root of unity.

Comment: @DanielV so I get $lim_{n\to infty} cos(\frac{\pi k}{n})+isin(\frac{\pi k}{n})$?

Comment: @gbox Nope, look at demoivre's again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $\,\omega=\cfrac{1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}\,$ then $\omega^2=-\overline{\omega}\,$, $\omega^3 = -1\,$ and $\omega^6=1\,$, so the sequence $\omega^n$ is periodic and non-constant, therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: why do $\omega^2=-\overline{\omega}$?

Comment: @gbox That's easy enough to verify by direct calculation. Otherwise, since you noticed that $1+\sqrt{3}i$ $=2e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}\,$, that implies $\omega^3 = e^{\pi i} = -1\,$, and then $\omega^2 = \frac{-1}{\omega} = - \overline{\omega}\,$ (where $\frac{1}{\omega} = \overline{\omega}$ follows from $|\omega|=1\,$).

Answer (score 1):

Let’s call your number $\frac{1+\sqrt3i}2=z$. You want to notice that $|z|=1$, since $(\frac12)^2+(\frac{\sqrt3}2)^2=1$. This means that the powers of $z$ bounce around on the unit circle, never changing their distance from the origin. So no limit! A closer examination shows that $z$ is a sixth root of $1$, so that its powers actually take on only six different values.

Comment: Staying along the unit circle doesn't imply the lack of a limit.  For example, $z^{1/n}$

Comment: Quite right, @DanielV, i should have specified that $|z^n-z^{n-1}|=1$ also.